# Where to deallocate (free)

Tags: c, valgrind

Studying a tutorial on linked lists in C. I've compiled this code and ran it through valgrind. It show's 4 allocations and 0 frees, which I understand. I need to know how to properly call `free()` to deallocate.

Code example: `llist2.c`

```
// linked list: inserting at the n'th position
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

typedef struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
} Node;

Node* head;

void Insert(int data, int n)
{
    Node* temp1 = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp1->data = data;
    temp1->next = NULL;

    if(n==1) { // list is empty, set next to head, initially NULL.
        temp1->next = head;
        head = temp1;
        return;
    }

    Node* temp2 = head;
    for(int i = 0; i < n-2; i+=1) {
        temp2 = temp2->next;
    }

    temp1->next = temp2->next;
    temp2->next = temp1;
}

void Print() {
    Node* temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    printf("\n");
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    head = NULL;
    Insert(2,1);
    Insert(3,2);
    Insert(4,1);
    Insert(5,2);
    Print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example._

Comment: You are not implementing any "delete" operation, so there is no real memory leak (all of the requested memory is accessible). While it is a little dirty to just allow the memory to be released when the process stop, is not that much of a problem. The issue would be if you, say, deleted a node (which would no longer be accessible) and you did not free the memory.

Comment: From where should i call free?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a function to free your list.

```
void freelist(Node* head)
{
    Node *next,*curr;
    curr = head;
    while (curr != NULL)
    {
       next = curr -> next;
       free(curr);
       curr = next;
    }
}
```

You can call this in main at the end.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Other code

    freelist(head);
    head = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should deallocate after finished using what is allocated. Follow the list and deallocate.

For example, you can call this function `Deallocate()` after calling `Print()`.

```
void Deallocate() {
    Node* temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL) {
        Node* next = temp->next;
        free(temp);
        temp = next;
    }
    head = NULL;
}
```

Note that you cannot do like this

```
void Deallocate_bad() {
    Node* temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL) {
        free(temp);
        temp = temp->next; /* undefined behavior */
    }
    head = NULL;
}
```

because you cannot access `temp->next` after deallocating `temp`.